# Univariate optimization done in more dimensions

Tags: optimization, terminology

Assume you have a univariate scalar function you want to minimize, i.e. we want:
$$\min_x f(x).$$
The function $f(x)$, is however quite ugly.

In my situation we have found that dividing the problem into: $g(y,x)$, such that $g(x, x) = f(x)$ helps in practice. In empirical studies it is found that iterating:
$$y_{t+1} = \arg\min_y g(y, x_t),$$
$$x_{t+1} = \arg\min_x g(y_{t+1}, x),$$
gives satisfying results.

Then comes my question: Any pointers to what the approach is called? And what would guarantee convergence? My initial thinking is that convexity would guarantee global convergence, but would any other weaker assumptions help the situation?

Edit: A very simple example could be considering: $f(x) = x^4 + x^2$, with $g(x, y) = x^4 + y^2$.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I have added one as an edit now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of duplicating variables and relaxing the constraint that they must be equal is called *Lagrangian decomposition*.

The idea of minimizing with respect to one variable at a time is called [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent).

Not sure there is a name for the combination of these two ideas.